# SSRS - Subreports leave blank white space if they have no info

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have several subreports that contain data that is either shown or hidden. This is how the design looks like:

[image]

As you can see, they are small but if one of the reports have no data, then the whitespace is still displayed when previewing the report:

[image]

I tested the subreports out by putting a solid black line as border and as you can see, the whitespace is generated even though the subreport returns no data.

How do I hide the whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

You could nest the subreport in a rectangle and control the visibility of the rectangle based on if there are any rows returned.

```
=IIF(Fields!Field1.Value IS NOTHING,true,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could show/hide Subreport based on Expression as

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing)>0,False,True)
```